# Using an index in variadic function template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <std::size_t N, class... Args>
using type = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;

template<typename ...Args, typename Func>
typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type functionOnParams(Func fp, Args&&...args)
{
  using Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>;

  int ints[2] = {1,2};
    return fp(std::forward<Args>( static_cast<type<index_of_args, Args...>>(ints[index_of_args++]) )...);
}
```

Hi,
I have spent a number of hours trying to figure to how to get the index_of_args for the above code.  Any help would be appreciated.  My searches keep going around in circles. index_of_args does not exist. I need to generate this index for each element of the std::forward.
Thank you

Comment: It would help if you explain what you're trying to achieve. There may be an even simpler solution.

Comment: index_of_args does not exist.  I need to generate this index from the std::forward<Args>. I wish to be able to pass a function(C) and some data(B) to a templated function(A).  The templated function(A) will derive the parameters from the data(B) and pass them to the function(C), with static_casts dependant on the parameter types required by the function(C).

Comment: An example of use would be functionOnParams<int,float> (&testPrint::printTwoNumbers, 2, 3.0) or even functionOnParams (&testPrint::printTwoNumbers, 2, 3.0), if the types can be deduced.  Both of these should print 1 and 2.0 from ints.

Comment: That looks just like std::invoke?

Comment: What's that `ints` array used for?

Comment: Can't you just write `ints[0], ints[1]`? The length is fixed.

Comment: ints is just a simple example of some alternative data. Later, I will be passing data to functionOnParams as a parameter.  I wanted to keep it simple until I figure out this step. Thanks for the interest so far.

Comment: Why you want to pass parameters which are later not used. Instead, as I understand, you want to pass data which is present in some other storage ( here you named that ints )

Answer (score 1):

you can get make an `std::index_sequence` from `Args` and pass them to a helper function (by *template arguments deduction*). and then do anything you want in the helper function.

```cpp
template<typename Func, typename... Args, size_t... Is, typename RealArgs>
std::invoke_result_t<Func&&, Args&&...> helper(Func&& func, std::index_sequence<Is...>* indicesTag, std::tuple<Args...>* argsTypeTag, RealArgs&& args){
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(std::forward<RealArgs>(args)[Is])...);
}
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
std::invoke_result_t<Func&&, Args&&...> functionOnParams(Func&& func, Args&&... args){
    int a[] = { 0, 1 };
    return helper(std::forward<Func>(func), (std::index_sequence_for<Args...>*)nullptr, (std::tuple<Args...>*)nullptr, a /* anything to replace the arguments */);
}


int main(){
    auto x = functionOnParams(std::plus<>(), 0, 1.0f);
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

in the other hand, you can also use *class template specialization* to pass the `std::index_sequence` and `Args`.

```cpp
template<typename, typename>
struct Helper;
template<typename... Args, size_t... Is>
struct Helper<std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::tuple<Args...>>{
    template<typename Func, typename RealArgs>
    static std::invoke_result_t<Func&&, Args&&...> call(Func&& func, RealArgs&& args){
        return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(std::forward<RealArgs>(args)[Is])...);
    }
};
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
std::invoke_result_t<Func&&, Args&&...> functionOnParams(Func&& func, Args&&... args){
    int a[] = { 0, 1 };
    return Helper<std::index_sequence_for<Args...>, std::tuple<Args...>>::call(std::forward<Func>(func), a /* anything to replace the arguments */);
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you RedFog.  Just what I need.  Computer languages really appear to slowly paint themselves into corners.